# Java ME on Siemens CX70

Tags: java, eclipse, mobile, netbeans, java-me

I have very old Siemens CX70 in working state and just don't want to throw it out. My idea is to use its math power and peripherals (GSM module, USB, Camera and screen) to build some simple applications for home use (multichannel termometer, timer and cheap security system - for examples).

I know I should use Java ME and IDE (I love Netbeans, for example). Can you tell me what I need more to start developing? I know Java well, I just need to make an environment to developing, debug and deploy. Mobile library documentation will be very helpful too.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know `J2ME` programming? And have you installed Your IDE and Compiler yet?

Comment: @CoolGuy I know Java SE, I think Java ME is not so different. I have installed NetBeans and JavaME plugin. I've installed JavaME SDK, but haven't idea how to use all these.

Comment: Well,does a HelloWorld program compile?

Comment: @CoolGuy Nah, can't compile. I have default code created (right after created a project) and it says "Can not locate java.lang" http://epsiloncool.ru/i/E20140909-211455-001.png

Answer (score 0):

There are so many online tutorials about this topic that the only right thing to do is to refer you to google.com
Search after "getting started with j2me".

However, there's something else you should know upfront before getting too excited.

The security model in JavaME will prevent you from doing much useful stuff, in relation to some of the things you mention.
Every time you try to access certain things in the phone, like e.g. the camera, or send SMS, or read/write a file on SD card, etc etc - the phone will show a popup "This app is trying to access camera. Allow this?". And the app will only continue after a manual click on Yes.

As you can imagine, this of course renders a lot of ideas useless.

In order to prevent these popups, you can sign your app with a certificate you buy from Thawte or Verisign. But as that'll cost you $300 a year, it's not the way most sparetime hobby developers chooses.

Personally, I found another way, but it requires you to use a phone from Sony Ericsson.
Because the old Sony Ericsson phones can be patched in order to remove the Java security. After doing this on one of my old phones, I've been having fun making apps like the ones you mention. For example, an app that keeps an eye on my home when we're out, by taking a picture every second. If it detects a difference in the picture, it sends me an MMS with the picture. :-)

I have searched a long time for patching options for other brands, but I just can't find anything useful. Nokia should supposedly also be patchable, but I just can't find anything useful about it.

So in short: If you'd like to make some sparetime hobby apps on a phone like that, you should either find a Sony Ericsson phone and patch it - or go dig up an old used Android device.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have java code certificate from Digicert which I using to sign my java applets (about $200 per year). Could it work for Java ME? Other question: should I have a certificate too if I need access Android camera/sms list etc?

Comment: I don't know if Digicert will work. I don't think so, but you could try. For Android you don't need an expensive certificate. You can simply create your own certificate.